# Jquery append to <head> not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meta

For some reason this block of code will not work. It refuses to put in the meta tag within the head. Any ideas ?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>hello world</title>
</head>

<body>
HELLO WORLD!

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("head").append("<meta blabla>");
});
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Append to <head>? Seems like a bad design idea to beginning with. That should be done server side

Comment: Why do you want to append a meta tag with document.ready? Why not just put it there directly, am I missing something?

Comment: my friend actually has some of those.. templated websites where you can only modify content. I was just trying to figure out a way for him to just jquery to insert meta data in for pinterest

Comment: @mildse7en What metadata? If it's for a server to parse, like Facebook's `<meta property="og:title" content="Film Title"/>`, jQuery is not going to help you (for the reason you noted in the difference between View Source and Inspector).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is actually working. It will not show up if you view source because the source is the original HTML file. For example, if you try appending a string to the body, it will show up, however, if you view the source, there is no trace of the string in the body.

ex

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("body").append("random sentence");});
</script>
```

Comment: That's because view source views the source, which is static as it was initially loaded, but inspector views the current, rendered DOM.

Answer (score 2):

It does work, http://jsfiddle.net/LGnxg/

```
$(function(){
   $('head').append('<meta test="true"/>'); 
});
```

You're missing the closing /> in the meta tag. This indicates to jQuery that this is an element to be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

The code run correctly in my compute.

My test enviroment is following:
System : window vista 
Browser : chrome  && firefox
Jquery : jquery-1.8.3.min.js

So can you provide more information?